# Github Clans Floating Action Button

Tags: android, android-studio, floating-action-button

I'am using Floating Action Menus.
What I want is when the user clicked the FAB,
The current frame/activity's Background will change.
If you are familiar with skype android app,
When you click the FAB on that app,
I am making similar.

My XML is like this.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.toweelo.fragments.Nearby"
>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/googleMap"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvNearby"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="50"
    fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
    fab:menu_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
    fab:menu_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    fab:menu_colorRipple="@color/colorAccent"
    fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
    fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
    fab:menu_openDirection="up"
    fab:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
    fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
    fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
    fab:menu_shadowYOffset="3dp"
    fab:menu_showShadow="true">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/menuIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_replay"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorAccent"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/menuOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_replay"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorAccent"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_replay"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorAccent"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
```

How can i make it behavior like skype app? thanks..